# Drag and Drop from ListView to activity

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

I have an App which I want to have an option of dragging items from a listview to an activity, the listview is in the same activity I wish to drop my items into, I have done my research and I cannot figure out how I can make this work, all help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to drag an item from a Fragment of a ListView to another fragment of an Activity?

Comment: no, I have a relativelayout half of it is my listview, i want to drag item my listview to my other part of the relativelayout, initially my app stores images, i wanna be able to drag an image from my listview to my relativelayout where at drop point i want to create(dynamically) an imageview to hold the image

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the progress is in your project. Let me start at Google's webpage @ [Drag and Drop](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html). There are sample codes using one layout (implied). A long time ago, I did try it and worked.

Perhaps show some code and layout xml file, and we can help you better.